# Carry a var to a location after successfully inserting data

Tags: php

So I got data entry that ends with a header to a location (index.php), wanted to set a var `$successMsg = "Good";`

and to display it on the index.php page.

```
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $insertData)) {
   $successMsg = "Good";
   header("Location: ../index.php?success");
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?failed");
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

That way on index.php it will echo $successMsg

Comment: <?php
header("Location: /new-page.php", true, 301);
exit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the message as a GET variable

if you use the following instead of the above

```php
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $insertData)) {
   $successMsg = "Good";
   header("Location: ../index.php?success_msg=$successMsg&status=success");
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?success_msg=$successMsg&status=failed");
}
```

then in index.php you have the variable in the $_GET array

```php
echo $_GET['success_msg'];
```